# Render/Dispaly and Play youtube video embedded in pdf, Android

Tags: android, pdf-reader, pdfrenderer, pdf-rendering

I have an PDF that contains hyperlinks and YouTube video embedded in it.

**Target :** Need to open PDF and all hyperlinks and videos should be working.

**Findings :** I have tried many of projects and third-party applications. Most of them use MuPDF, and are unable to play YouTube videos.

I can try out with native or PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

We added support for YouTube and oder embedded media in v1.2 of PSPDFKit for Android. It's a commercial library and I am part of the team that builds it. Head over to https://pspdfkit.com/ and try the demo.

We're using the [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) on Android to show the videos. If you implement your own PDF rendering engine, this is definitely a good start. Synchronizing everything up turned out to be very tricky, and we ended re-implementing a custom scroll view to have maximum control over all aspects.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers to your own site. Instead, put the essential information in your answer itself. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212/200235)